# Issue in flash course due to auto logout in Moodle

Tags: flash, moodle

My Moodle version is 2.3.1
I am uploading flash course having 2 different windows 1 is launcher page from which I am launching the actual course in another window which contains flash content for learning purpose. Recently I found a problem due to Auto logout feature of Moodle LMS which is as below. When I launch course from launcher window it works fine, when the Moodle did auto log out after particular time the SCORM tracking stops and no data updated on Moodle for that user but API communication continues without error code and hence my main course window continues the course without any issue and without any tracking on Moodle. This causes that user able to complete the course but no tracking details found at LMS end. So how to identify in the course that Moodle has executed the auto logout and no data being sent to the LMS so that I can at least inform user that stop taking this course as it has lost communication with LMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most the time the SCO looks up the SCORM Runtime once, and then continues to communicate with the API reference it found.  There typically is a "findAPI" algorithm which looks across the DOM, between windows for this runtime API actually just called "API" in this case.  The Runtime could be hiding in a parent window, a frame, etc...

If the content is built using a 3rd Party tool, or if its custom, you may want to research the JavaScript files to see if you can determine exactly where this API lookup is occurring.  Then, you'd have to periodically check to see if the API is present so you could catch the loss of the Runtime.

If you can't find the code however, you can use your own to establish whether the Runtime API is present.  I've also seen cases on mobile where if the LMS launched in a new tab, and the content is large enough it runs out of memory and other tabs get hibernated.  That can also lead to data loss.

You could use the SCORM 1.2 portion since this is Moodle -

```
var API = {},
    win;
// FindAPI Method
function findAPI(win) {
    var attempts = 0, limit = 500;
    while ((!win.API && !win.API_1484_11) && (win.parent) && (win.parent !== win) && (attempts <= limit)) {
        attempts += 1;
        win = win.parent;
    }
    if (win.API_1484_11) {//SCORM 2004-specific API.
        API.version = "2004";
        //Set version
        API.path = win.API_1484_11;
    } else if (win.API) {//SCORM 1.2-specific API
        API.version = "1.2";
        //Set version
        API.path = win.API;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
/* returns {boolean} API found true, false if not*/
function checkAPI() {
    try {
        win = window.parent;
        if (win && win !== window) {
            findAPI(window.parent);
        }
    } catch (e) {/* Cross Domain issue */
        // send to console?
    }
    if (!API.path) {
        try {
            win = window.top.opener;
            findAPI(win);
        } catch (ee) {/* Cross domain issue */
            // Send to console?
        }
    }
    if (API.path) {
        API.connection = true;
        return true;
    }
    // Could not locate the API -  throw error
    return false;
}
```

It occurred to me you may be able to just adjust Administration► Server► Session Handling ► Timeout in Moodle.  That may get you around the aggravation of updating all your content.